# Integrate OpenAI on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, openai-api

I'm creating a simple script to call the OpenAI API through Google App Script and send it several prompts at the same time to write the answers in column B: For that purpose, I create an array with the prompts from column A, I loop through them calling the API and writing values in column B.

This is the code:

```
function gpt3_response(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var ufila = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A2:A" + ufila);
  var vector = range.getValues().flat();
  var API_KEY = "XXXXX";
  var data = {
    "model": "text-davinci-003",
    'max_tokens': 220,
    'temperature': 0,
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
    'headers': {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + API_KEY,
    },
  };
  const recorreArray = vector => vector.forEach((prompt, index) => {
    data['prompt'] = prompt;
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions',
      options,
    )
    var respuesta = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())['choices'][0]['text'];
    sheet.getRange(`B${index + 2}:B${index + 2}`).setValue(respuesta);
  });
  recorreArray(vector);
}
```

However, the response is:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.User;
import com.example.demo.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(""/user"")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping(""/all"")
    public List<User> getAllUsers(){
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping(""/add"")
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userService.addUser(user);
    }

    @PutMapping(""/update"")
    public void updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
        userService.updateUser(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping
```

Someone knows whats happen? If I call the API with only one prompt, the response its ok, but when I try to make a loop calling the API many times, the response is what I show on top

I'm trying to make a call to OpenAI API through a loop with many prompts at the same time, and writing each response on the column B

Comment: Welcome to [so]  Please add some sample data, clarify if the above iis wrote to a single cell, multiple cells or as an error message.

Comment: Are you saying that the response from OpenAI is Java code? I'm unclear on the issue here

Answer (score -1):

```
function OpenAI_Ask(API_KEY, Model, Prompt, Temperature, Tokens) {
  // Set the API endpoint for ChatGPT
  var apiEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions";

  // Set the options for the API call
  var options = {
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + API_KEY
    },
  "payload": JSON.stringify(
    {
    "model": Model,
    "prompt": Prompt,
    "max_tokens": Tokens
    },
  ),
  "method": "POST",
  "temperature": Temperature
  };

  // Make the API call to ChatGPT
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiEndpoint, options);

  // Parse the response from ChatGPT
  var responseObject = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // Print the generated text from ChatGPT
  var Choice = responseObject.choices[0].text;
  return Choice;
}

function OpenAI_Test()
{
  var API_KEY = 'YOUR-API-KEY-HERE'; ;
  var PROMPT  = 'What is your favorite color?';
  var MODEL   = 'text-davinci-003';
  var TEMPERATURE = 0.5;
  var TOKENS   = 200;
  var Answer = OpenAI_Ask(API_KEY, MODEL, PROMPT, TEMPERATURE, TOKENS);
  Logger.log(Answer);
}
```

There is a sample Google Sheet you can copy with code and test harness [here](https://primarygoals.com/OpenAISheets).

Comment: Please explain how this answer the question. P.S. It looks that the temperature property is misplaced. It should be included in the payload JSON.